# How to add user defined row into a datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have datagridview which is filled with values from DB when button clicked.

All these happen based on a condition from radiobutton.

Now i need to add some extra row (default value) into the datatable, each time these conditions apply.

When button clicked and radiobutton condition apply,these codes will happen.

```
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            string query = "SELECT type,priceS FROM service WHERE type='" + button5.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            dt.SelectCommand = cmd;
        }dt.Fill(tt);                
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;
```

The query will return

> string =type and int=priceS

from DB, i just need add string "S" with the "type" value

For example: if type = Style then in the datatable it be should "Style(S)"

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Datatables i solved it in the MySQL Query itself

> Query="Select Concat(type,'S'),price from service"

This will add the string S with that of the type's value.